# Using webshims polyfill in an Angular app

Tags: jquery, forms, angularjs, polyfills, webshim

I'm trying to use the [webshims polyfill](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim) in an angular app, which is also using requirejs for dependency management. I'm trying to shim the absence of the `form` attribute in form fields like `input` and `button`, which tells the browser which form a particular button or input belongs to. IE9 lacks this feature.

I figured that the best way to use this polyfill would be to create a form directive, and invoke the `$.webshims.polyfill('forms')` inside the link function.

The directive

```
define(['angular', 'webshims'], function(angular) {
  return angular.module('myApp').directive('form', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        if (!(window.Modernizr.input.placeholder || window.Modernizr.input.autofocus)) {
          $.webshims.setOptions({
            waitReady: false
          });
          $.webshims.polyfill('forms');
        }
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Here is how I'm loading the webshims polyfill right now:

My Requirejs config

```
app: {
  options: {
    baseUrl: 'src/apps',
    stubModules: ['cs'],
    paths: {
      jquery: '../public/components/jquery/jquery',
      ....
      angular: '../public/components/angular/angular',
      ....
      webshims: '../public/components/webshim/src/polyfiller',
    },
    shim: {
      angular: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'angular'
      },
      ...
      priority: ['angular']
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is that even though the shim loads, and even calls the correct functions, the shims don't seem to be working, as IE9 still has problems with HTML5 Form attributes (placeholder, the **form** attribute, etc)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with angular, so I don't know wether your descision to do this in a "form" directive is right (But I doubt it).

But first: webshims polyfiller file registers as a named amd module called 'polyfiller'. It would be good to rename your webshims into polyfiller

```
define(['angular', 'polyfiller'], function(angular)
```

and:

```
polyfiller: '../public/components/webshim/src/polyfiller',
```

inside of your define function you should also set the basePath correctly before you are calling the polyfill method:

```
webshims.setOptions({
   waitReady: false,
   basePath: '../public/components/webshim/src/shims/'
});
```

Additionally autofocus and placeholder are supported in IE10, but the form attribute isn't support even in IE11. So you should remove the Modernizr test.

So let's look what your current problem is.

Can you run the following code in IE9's console `webshims.isReady('forms')`?

If true:
If forms is ready, run the follwing code in IE9's console `$('body').updatePolyfill()`.
Does this help?

If false:
Run the following code in your IE9's console `webshims.modules["form-core"].loaded`

Does it return true or undefined/false.

If it returns undefined/false:
Make sure that a) webshims.polyfill('forms'); is really called and b) there is no network error -> The file is loaded without 404 also see the basePath config above.

---

Something about webshims loading and executing:

Normally you should load webshims once on your app initializing. And then everytime your view changes you should invoke the `.updatePolyfill` on the dom element that was changend.

Some frameworks have special events for this. For example jQuery mobile uses the pageinit event.

In this case (jQM) you would write:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(e){
    $(e.target).updatePolyfill();
});
```

In some frameworks you need to use a setTimeout:

```
render: function(target){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(target).updatePolyfill();
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I figured it out after some time, (didn't check SO).
The problem was that the basePath was being calculated incorrectly, so I had to pass that, and yes, the decision to use a form directive was not very bright itself, as the polyfill takes care of supported browsers.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: I have one small questions, I'm mainly concerned with IE9+ as of now. In IE9, even not calling updatePolyfill() on the element seems to not be causing any problem. I have switched views, created dynamic views, etc. I presume angular is somehow taking care of this in IE, *(even though I'm not using the directive now, where I'd normally put this code...)*

Comment: I can't say. The form attribute polyfill doesn't need an updatePolyfill call. If placeholder still works, Angular seems to cache the rendered markup somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed troubleshooting. For those trying to use `<input type='date'>` (or any other partial support element) in an angular directive as I was, you can include the call to `$('body').updatePolyfill()` in the `link` function of your directive. This should ensure the polyfiller runs whenever the shimmed element is instantiated. I think it would be better to configure webshims as a service, but I haven't got that going yet.

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into this issue myself and I think I have a simpler solution which seems to work fine:

Just call the updatePolyFill method from the controller of your main index page after a view loads:

```
//Polyfill needs update when dynamic view loads
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $('body').updatePolyfill();
});
```

The trick is that this event bubbles **up** from the view in the ng-view block so you need to do this in the controller above that view, not in the view's controller.  Also, I guess, it should not be called if it's not polyfilling already, not sure how to do that yet though and it didn't appear to conflict at all testing with Chrome which needs no polyfills for what I'm doing (form controls only).